# In quick sort, if the pivotal element is always chosen to be the middle element, will it become same as merge sort?

Tags: algorithm

In
quick sort, if the pivotal element is always chosen to be the middle element, will it become
same as merge sort?

Comment: _"become same as merge sort"_. How do you define _similarity_?

Comment: No. You can't know where the pivot element ends up after partitioning. These are different algorithms anyway. If you consider recursive implementations, mergesort is called on each half of the array. After that call, you know that each half taken by itself is sorted and then sort the whole array by merging. In quicksort, you partition the array first. After that, you know that all elements left of the pivot are less than the pivot and all elements to the right are not less. You also know that the pivot is in its correct position. Then you call quicksort on the left and rght partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Quicksort and merge sort are two different algorithms.

- **Quicksort:** hard work when splitting the array; recursive calls on each half; no need for hard work to put the two halves together.
- **Merge sort:** no need for hard work when splitting the array; recursive calls on each half; hard work to put the two halves together.

As a summary, the hard work of quicksort is done during the **partitionning** step, and the hard work of merge sort is done during the **merging** step.

### Similarity between the two algorithms: they both sort the array

In any case, Quicksort and Merge sort will both sort the array. So, seen from the outside, it doesn't matter which algorithm you use, the result will always be the same. In that sense, yes, Quicksort and Merge sort are similar. They solve the same problem: sorting an array.

At least, this is true in the case where distinct elements compare different. In the case where two elements might be distinct, but compare equal, then the orders produced by Quicksort and Merge sort might be different. For instance, if you are sorting a list of students in order of their grade, then two distinct students might have the same grade; in that case, there is a "tie" between those two students, and merge sort and quicksort might break the tie arbitrarily in two different fashions. Merge sort is typically a "stable" sort, meaning the relative order of tied elements will be the same as their relative order in the original unsorted list; quicksort is typically not stable, and much more unpredictable.

### Difference and similarity in time complexity

The time complexity of comparison-based sorting algorithms is traditionally evaluated in the number of comparisons performed by the algorithm, expressed as a function of the number of elements in the array.

Let us call `n` the number of elements in the array.

- Merge sort always takes about `n log(n)` comparisons.
- Quicksort takes between `n log(n)` and `n²` comparisons. Yes, if you are lucky and the selected pivot is always the median of the subarray being sorted, then quicksort will take about `n log(n)` comparisons, the same number as Merge sort.

In that sense, yes, if quicksort is magically lucky and the selected pivot is always the median, then quicksort and merge sort will have the same time complexity.

Comment: Given how trivial it is to make mergesort stable, I'd consider a non-stable mergesort to be buggy/wrong (except when there's a decent reason, like if it's an in-place mergesort, where stability isn't trivial).

Comment: @KellyBundy But quicksort is usually not stable.

Comment: Which is why I only spoke about mergesort :-). I'm not saying there's something wrong (I'm the upvoter), just wanted to point out that mergesort's "arbitrary" tie-breaking should be stability. Which I wouldn't really call arbitrary, or at least it's far less arbitrary than what quicksort does (which even rather seems *random* to me).

Comment: @KellyBundy I added a sentence *"Merge sort is typically a "stable" sort, meaning the relative order of tied elements will be the same as their relative order in the original unsorted list; quicksort is typically not stable, and much more unpredictable."*